# What comes into mind of a native speaker on "Please do it yourself!”?

Tags: idiom-meaning

I have read a sign which started with "Please do it yourself!". I read it and started laughing. May be because a possible special meaning of "it" or "do it" like in "do it with somebody". Is this special meaning associated for a  native speaker? Is it awkward to write or say "Please do it yourself!"?

Background:
The sign was about the coffee brewer. The sign was saying that the staff will not fill in the water for you.

Comment: I assume you are referring to 'it' as a euphemism for sex? You don't say what the sign was about. If 'it' clearly refers to something practical, most people would not understand it in a sexual sense unless they were deliberately looking for innuendo.

Comment: On first reading, I thought it referred to DIY of the IKEA sort (assembling furniture etc).

Comment: I think this is a good question; it shows the importance of preposition choice and phrasal verbs.

Answer (score 0):

The presence or absence and choice of prepositions can make an enormous difference in the meaning of an English verb. See for example "[phrasal verbs](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs)".

If you "**do it *with* someone**" or "**do it *to* someone**", the phrasal constructions "*do with*" and "*do to*" could be construed as meaning "have sex with", especially if the referent is animate. I think this is the sense you found humorous - as if someone had said "do it *with* yourself" or "do it *to* yourself.

And there is also a sense of "*do it*" without a preposition that can mean "have sex"; e.g. "John and I did it." can mean "John and I had sex" but it requires a plural subject.

But the phrase "**Do it yourself**" is a different construction than these. In fact it's a common enough English phrase that it has a well-known initialism: "[DIY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/DIY)" It carries no connotation of sex. It just simply means "Perform some action on your own".